# I am using setTimeout() to call a refresh function, but it doesnt stop calling refresh when I move to another component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular, and I am having a function, refresh, which i need to call after every 1 min but when I am into that component it works fine and when i navigate to some other view it is still calling the refresh function, refresh function is called in ngOnInit() and then this setTimeout() function i have created in the refresh() function only.

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.refresh();
 }
 ...
 ...

refresh(){
...
...

setTimeout(() => {
  this.refresh();
   },10000) 
 }
```

Comment: You have created a recursive call without any condition to stop it.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to know how do I stop it, first I was using subscribe and unsubscribe but then first it stops the interval if a navigate to another page, but then when I come back to the same page, it starts again but never stops. But i'll try these 2 answers

Comment: you can put a condition either before calling setTimeout or before calling refresh from within setTimeout. Either of the given answers would work for youy use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one more property like `timeout` and update your class like so,

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.refresh();
 }
 ...
 ...
timeout;
refresh(){
...
...

this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  this.refresh();
   },10000) 
 }
```

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```

Your class will have to implement `OnDestroy` interface for this besides `OnInit`.

Although for your use case, `setInterval` makes more sense and also you can make a reusable service like `IntervalService` to encapsulate the whole behaviour.

The setInterval bit :-

```
interval;

ngOnInit()
{
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   this.refresh();
}, 10000);
}
ngOnDestroy(){
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}

refresh(){....}
```

Comment: It works fine when i navigate to some other view , but when i again want to go back to the same view this function setInterval gets invoked and then when i again change the view the refresh() is getting called then also. What am I missing?

Comment: You're starting the interval inside the init lifecycle method only right ? If your refresh calls an API and you are resolving a promise then it's quite possible that the API resolves after your component has already called the destroy lifecycle method but the interval should have definitely stopped. You can replace the promise bit with subscribe/unsubscribe for no stale requests.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setInterval`instead of `setTimeout` and in ngOnDestroy you need to use  `clearInterval`

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
   this.refresh();
}, 10000);
```

Clear interval

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: It works fine when i navigate to some other view , but when i again want to go back to the same view, this function setInterval() gets invoked and then when i again change the view the refresh() is getting called then also. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to make sure that you are clearing `setInterval` in ngOnDestroy hook